# False positives from TypeScript for Redux Action Creator's function parameters?

Tags: typescript, redux

I've added a TypeScript type to my function parameter. I don't know if it matters but this function is a Redux Action Creator:

```
export const moveLayerUp = ({ index }: { index: number }) => {
  return {
    type: TYPES.MOVE_LAYER_UP,
    index
  };
};
```

To check it was working I changed the type to a string, which I expected to error. However it still works fine:

```
export const moveLayerUp = ({ index }: { index: string }) => {
  return {
    type: TYPES.MOVE_LAYER_UP,
    index
  };
};
```

I can see from the Redux dev tools that this function is defiantly being called. Should this be erroring when the type is wrong?

I used Create React App with the `--typescript` flag to create the project. In the tsconfig I set  `"strict": false` as I want to add types as I see fit rather than all the time.

UPDATE: The function that calls it is this:

```
  const handleUp = () => {
    moveLayerUp({ index });
  };
```

Comment: Could you provide the code where you're calling `moveLayerUp`? I suspect you are calling it with an `any` type or from a `.js` file which would not generate the error. I would also not recommend using typescript with `strict: false` it exposes you to a lot of subtle errors, maybe `strict: true, allowJs: true` would suit your needs better.

Comment: @jay_aye_see_kay Ive updated my question. The function that calls it does not define a type, is this necessary? Does this mean that `: { index: string }` is doing nothing? Im new to TypeScript but Im surprised if it works that way.

Comment: Yes you need type annotations on both the function implementation and everywhere you call the function. Otherwise TS can't check if they match. The reason I suggest leaving strict mode on is it will prevent implicit any types, as long as both files in your example are TS files you have to provide a type. If you want to opt out of typing for a function you can always just type it's inputs as any, but it's better to do it explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how index is declared for use in handleUp.  If it becomes of type 'any' then TypeScript treats it like a JavaScript variable and is very forgiving.  It will allow ducktyping as in JavaScript.  From what you say in your comment it sounds like this is the problem.

Consider the code below.  This compiles fine in TypeScript.  The declaration of index makes it of type 'any' and it gets cast to string when it's passed into moveLayerUp.  So index="1" in moveLayerUp.

```
const moveLayerUp = ({ index }: { index: string }) => { }

function callMoveLayerUp() {
    var index;
    index = 1;
    moveLayerUp({ index });
}
```

Now consider this code:

```
const moveLayerUp = ({ index }: { index: string }) => { }

function callMoveLayerUp() {
    var index: number;
    index = 1;
    moveLayerUp({ index });
}
```

The only difference is index is declared as of type 'number'.  This code won't compile in TypeScript.  You get an error in the call to moveLayerUp 'Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string''.  index is explicitly a number so you can't call a function that expects it to be a string.

This is why it's best to declare the types of all variables in TypeScript.